# Atomically copying one MySQL table over another?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to copy one table over another one "atomically".  Basically I want to update a table periodically, such that a process that reads from the table will not get an incomplete result if another process is updating the table.

To give some background info, I want a table that acts as a leaderboard for a game.  This leaderboard will update every few minutes via a separate process.  My thinking is as follows:

Table SCORES contains the publicly-viewable leaderboard that will be read from when a user views the leaderboard.  This table is updated every few minutes.  The process that updates the leaderboard will create a SCORES_TEMP table that contains the new leaderboard.  Once that table is created, I want to copy all of its contents over to SCORES "atomically".  I think what I want to do is something like:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE SCORES;
INSERT INTO SCORES SELECT * FROM SCORES_TEMP;
```

I want to replace everything in SCORES.  I don't need to maintain my primary keys or auto increment values.  I just want to bring in all the data from SCORES_TEMP.  But I know that if someone views the scores before these 2 statements are done, the leaderboard will be blank.  How can I do this atomically, such that it will never show blank or incomplete data?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [rename table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html)

```
RENAME TABLE old_table TO backup_table, new_table TO old_table;
```

It's atomic, works on all storage engines, and doesn't have to rebuild the indexes.

Comment: Transactions will definitely help now that I know they can accomplish the atomic needs that I have, but for simplicity, this table renaming solution is the best for this particular situation.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, because of [the behavior of TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate.html) I think you'll need to:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM SCORES;
INSERT INTO SCORES SELECT * FROM SCORES_TEMP;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

I'm not sure there's a way to make what is always effectively a DDL operation transaction safe.

Comment: DDL = data definition language - things like CREATE TABLE, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may use transactions (for `InnoDB`),

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM SCORES;
INSERT INTO SCORES SELECT * FROM SCORES_TEMP;
COMMIT;
```

or `LOCK TABLES` (for `MyISAM`):

```
LOCK TABLES;
DELETE FROM SCORES;
INSERT INTO SCORES SELECT * FROM SCORES_TEMP;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know hot MySQL deals with transaction, but in T-SQL you could write

```
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM SCORES
INSERT INTO SCORES SELECT * FROM SCORES_TEMP
COMMIT TRAN
```

This way your operation would be "atomic", but not instantaneous.